# How to get Excel conditional formating to recognize boolean operations

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have constructed a spreadsheet to color code incoming scientific data based on different levels of criteria.

My problem is with data coming in as 'less than'.

For example, if the data shows Benzene at <5, I need it recognize that as a number less than 5.

Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Offered an answer with some assumptions. Please add some screenshots of data you're working with and I'll update my answer as needed.

Comment: If you're looking to do a conditional format (which your tag suggests), you could use the formula "=OR($B2<5)" (assuming column B is where Benzene would reside), and assuming you want to highlight the whole row, select the whole spreadsheet, then select Condition Formatting.  If this is what you're after, I can post a more formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REPLACE` in excel to replace the `<` sign with an empty string, then reduce the value by 1.

`REPLACE` takes 4 parameters. Read more about it [here.](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php)

**For example:**

In cell B1 resides `=REPLACE(A1,1, 1, "" ) - 1`

```
Output:
    A1   B1
    <5   4
```

I'm not sure how specific you need your data to be, but it appears this would suffice given the current information.